# How do I retrieve web service data and place it in an html table?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

Is there a way to retrieve the json array from a web service and store it in a variable?

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1"></table>
```

And I populate it like so:

```
// JSON array
var myData = method to retrieve json data from web service

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
function buildHtmlTable() {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myData);

    for (var i = 0 ; i < myData.length ; i++) {
        var row$ = $('<tr/>');
        for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
            var cellValue = myData[i][columns[colIndex]];

            if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
            row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
        }
        $("#myTable").append(row$);
    }
}

function addAllColumnHeaders(myList) {
    var columnSet = [];
    var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

    for (var i = 0 ; i < myData.length ; i++) {
        var rowHash = myData[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1) {
                columnSet.push(key);
                headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
    }
    $("#myTable").append(headerTr$);

    return columnSet;
}
```

I have used the code found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmmulani/7MRx6/). In this example the array is directly in the Javascript but I want to retrieve my array from a web service. Is this possible?

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is Ajax. There are many tutorials out there.

Comment: Yes its possible, use `ajax` to get data to that `data`, then call `buildHtmlTable` in `success` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Look at documentation here for more details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
You will want to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ""
}).done(function(data) {
  buildHtmlTable(data);
});

function buildHtmlTable(myData) {
...
}
```

Comment: My ajax call never reaches done. Could this be due to a 401 error I am receiving?

Comment: 401 is unauthorized. I have no idea what technologies you are using on the server, but you need to be authorized to access that resource and apparently the call you are making isn't authorized.